# How do you put multiple indexes on a field using @index and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, indexing

Given two fields in a table I can create an index that encompases both as follows:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_REPORTID_RECNO")
private Integer reportId;

@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_REPORTID_RECNO")
private Integer recNo;
```

and I can create indexes on each column individually

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_REPORTID")
private Integer reportId;

@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_RECNO")
private Integer recNo;
```

But it doesnt let me do both, this doesn't seem to be allowed

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_REPORTID_RECNO")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_REPORTID")
private Integer reportId;

@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_REPORTID_RECNO")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_RECNO")
private Integer recNo;
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can specify the second index at class level:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(indexes = 
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_REPORTID_RECNO",
        columnNames = {"reportId", "recNo"})
)
public class MyEntity {
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_REPORTID")
    private Integer reportId;

    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_RECNO")
    private Integer recNo;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `The type Index is deprecated`. Any alternatives?